# Postman runs the API but gives an error in my code with 500 status code

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I have to call one post api. When I tried to call this api in postman, it gives success and run perfact.

But when I tried to hit this api in my code, it gives me internal server error (500 error code).

I tried with other solution like, converting my request model into json string and then convert to data. And pass that data into API. But still it gives me 500 status code.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance.

***Request Parameters***

```
{
"schedule_id": 1,
"date_of_survey": "2022-03-10",
"is_resolution_completed": 0,
"resolution_date": "",
"resolution_time": "",
"resolution_note": "",
"patient_id": 6,
"answers": [
    {
        "question_id":1,
        "option_id":2,
        "exceptiontxt":"",
        "selectedAnswer": "7"
    },
    {
        "question_id":2,
        "option_id":5,
        "exceptiontxt":"",
        "selectedAnswer": "No"
    },
    {
        "question_id":3,
        "option_id":7,
        "exceptiontxt":"",
        "selectedAnswer": "No"
    }
]
}
```

***My Request Class Model***

```
struct SubmitSurveyRequest: Encodable {
     var schedule_id: Int
     var date_of_survey: String
     var is_resolution_completed: Int
     var resolution_date, resolution_time, resolution_note: String
     var patient_id: Int
     var answers: [SubmitSurveyRequestAnswer]
}

struct SubmitSurveyRequestAnswer: Encodable {
     var question_id: Int
     var option_id: Int
     var exceptiontxt: String
     var selectedAnswer: String

}
```

***My API Calling Function***

```
static func callAPIRaw<E: Encodable, D: Decodable>(_ url: String,
                                                       params: E,
                                                       resultType: D.Type,
                                                       customHeader: HTTPHeaders? = headers,
                                                       httpMethod: HTTPMethod = .post,
                                                       _ completion: @escaping (Result<D, BaseError>) -> Void) {
    
    
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    var jsonData: Data = Data()
    
    do {
        jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(params)
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint("Error while encoding data (\(error.localizedDescription))")
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = httpMethod.rawValue
    request.headers = customHeader!
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    
    if Helper.checkInternetConnection() {
        AF.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
        AF.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                if response.value != nil, response.value is Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    //debugPrint(url, params, response.value ?? "")
                    let decodedData: D?
                    do {
                        
                        let status: Int = (response.value as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "status") as? Int ?? 0
                        let message: String = (response.value as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "msg") as? String ?? ""

                        //Status = 0 -> Fail, Status = 1 -> Success
                        if status == 0 {
                            if response.response!.statusCode == 500 {
                                completion(.failure(.otherError(msg: "internal_server_error".localized, code: response.response!.statusCode)))
                            } else if response.response!.statusCode == 401 {
                                Helper.logout()
                            } else {
                                completion(.failure(.otherError(msg: message, code: response.response!.statusCode)))
                            }
                        } else {
                            decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(resultType, from: response.data!)
                            completion(.success(decodedData!))
                        }
                        
                    } catch let error {
                        debugPrint("Error while decoding data (\(error.localizedDescription))")
                        completion(.failure(.otherError(code: response.response!.statusCode)))
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(.otherError(code: response.response!.statusCode)))
                }
            case .failure(_):
                completion(.failure(.otherError(code: response.response?.statusCode ?? 500)))
            }
            
        }
    } else {
        completion(.failure(.networkError()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Postman has a code generator that might help you. Along the right there is a symbol `</>` that can be used to convert the request into multiple formats. One of the options is Swift using URLSession (AF isn't really necessary). I'd start by importing that and printing the contents of your request and its request to the console, likely there is a difference on your side. Also worth checking when the server returns 500, does it return any details with it. The server may be returning something like "invalid schedule_id " inside the body, explaining the issue

Comment: Set a breakpoint at 'request.httpBody = jsonData' and try 'po String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)' in the console. Compare it to your previous data.

Comment: Also, contentype header is important for most apis.

Comment: Show us the cURL request that is made successfully in Postman and then we can compare if the request you configured is the same as the one postman executes.

Comment: Also as an FYI using force unwrapping "!" is incredibly dangerous and will cause your code to crash. It should be avoided at all costs. Use `if let` or `guard` to unwrap things safely. Your function `callAPIRaw` specifies `customHeader` as optional, but supplies a default value, not necessary for it to be optional

Comment: @burnsi Yes, I missed the header content-type that's why it returns 500. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Yes, when it gives me error with 500 code, server returning like "invalid schedule_id". And Thank you so much for the advice about force unwrapping. I'll change my code to avoid crash.

Comment: Alamofire can generate `cURL` command (with `cURLDescription()`: `AF.request(request).cURLDescription{ print("Curl cmd: \($0)") }responseJSON {... }` ), and Postman too. You can compare and find the difference. If you still have issue, you can show the two outputs here (hide private properties if needed, like base URL, etc.)